How to filter inside Master Details table
I am mui data grid table with master details. Now I want to use filter with parent table and it should work on the child table as well which works fine with the below code.
const initialState = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
        apiRef,
        initialState: {
            filter: {
                filterModel: {
                    items: [],
                    quickFilterValues: ["firs"],
                    quickFilterLogicOperator: GridLogicOperator.Or
                }
            }
        },
    });
    const initialStateContentPanel = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
        apiRef,
        initialState: {
            filter: {
                filterModel: {
                    items: [],
                    quickFilterValues: ["firs"],
                    quickFilterLogicOperator: GridLogicOperator.Or
                }
            }
        },
    });

However when it finds something in the child table not in parent then it does not return anything. It should work as row grouping in which whatever we find in the grouped rows it returns. Kindly help
